# $\{x_n\}$ is an unbounded increasing sequence. Prove that $\exists \lim_n {K_n\over n} =L \iff \exists \lim_n{n\over x_n} =L$, where $K_n$...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be an unbounded increasing sequence such that $x_n \ne 0$ and $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $K_n$ define the number of terms in $\{x_n\}$ such that:
>   $$
> x_n \le n, n\in\Bbb N
> $$
>   Prove that if:
>   $$
> \exists \lim_{n\to\infty} {K_n\over n} = L_1
> $$
>   then:
>   $$
> \exists \lim_{n\to\infty} {n\over x_n} = L_2
> $$
>   and vice versa. And:
>   $$
> L_1 = L_2
> $$

I've started with putting down given facts. First $x_n$ in increasing and unbounded:
$$
\forall M\in\Bbb R\ \exists n \in\Bbb N: x_n > M\\
x_{n+1} > x_n
$$

This implies:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = +\infty
$$

Next, we have $K_n$ which define a number of terms in $x_n$ which are less or equal than $n$. This means $K_n$ is never larger than $n$, which in terms imply:
$$
\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}{K_n\over n} = L \in [0, 1]
$$

In case the limit exists then it must be somewhere in $[0, 1]$. Going back to the problem, what we want to prove is:
$$
\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}{K_n\over n} = L \iff  \exists \lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over x_n} = L
$$
And the problem splits into two parts, proving $\implies$ and proving $\impliedby$. 
This is where I'm not sure how to start.

---

To get some insight I decided to consider a couple of examples for $x_n$. Consider the following sequence:
$$
x_n = n - {1\over 2} = \left\{{1\over 2}, {3\over 2}, {5\over 2}, \dots \right\}
$$

Clearly, the number of terms not exceeding $n$ is itself $n$, because every term of $x_n$ is less than $n$. So:
$$
K_n = \{1, 2, 3, \dots n\}
$$

And then both limits exist:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} {K_n\over n} = 1 \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} {n\over n - {1\over 2}} = 1
$$

Let's also try to consider the following sequence:
$$
x_n = n + {1\over 2} = \left\{{3\over 2}, {5\over 2}, \dots \right\}
$$
Thus:
$$ 
K_n = \{0, 1, 2, \dots \} = n - 1
$$
Therefore:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{K_n\over n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}{n-1\over n} = 1
$$
And:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over x_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over n + {1\over 2}} = 1
$$

The staments holds for both examples, but:

> How do I prove this in general?

Comment: @MartinR I've just looked in that question, but unfortunately the answer is not full in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $j_0$ sufficiently large such that $x_j > 0$ for $j \ge j_0$. For each $j \ge j_0$ there is a non-negative integer $m_j$ such that
$$
   m_j < x_j \le m_j + 1 \, .
$$
Then
$$
   K_{m_j} < j \le K_{m_j+1}
$$
and therefore
$$
 \frac{K_{m_j}}{m_j+1} \le \frac{K_{m_j}}{x_j} < \frac{j}{x_j}
\le \frac{K_{m_j+1}}{x_j} < \frac{K_{m_j+1}}{m_j}
$$
$(x_j)$ is unbounded, so that $j \to \infty$ implies $m_j \to \infty$, and therefore
$$
 \lim_{j \to \infty } \frac{K_{m_j}}{m_j+1} = \lim_{j \to \infty } \frac{K_{m_j+1}}{m_j} = L_1
$$
and the conclusion follows with the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, should it be $j \le K_{m(j) + 1}$ instead of $j \le K_{m(j+1)}$?

Comment: @roman: Yes, indeed, that was a typo.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where it follows from that: $K_{m_j} < j < K_{m_j + 1}$. That's the only part left I'm trying to wrap my mind on.

Comment: @roman: If  $x_j \le m_j + 1$ then  at least $j$ sequence elements ($x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_j $) are counted in $K_{m_j+1}$, therefore $K_{m_j+1} \ge j$. And if $x_j > m_j$ then there are at most $(j-1)$ sequence elements ($x_1, \ldots, x_{j-1}$) counted in $K_{m_j}$, so that $K_{m_j} < j$.

Comment: That's all clear now. Many thanks to you!